# Google place API invoice

Tags: google-places-api, google-nearby

I have a problem that I can't understand with the google place api.

I don't use atmosphere Data or Contact Data, but Google generates an exorbitant bill.

I would also like to know if you can give me a tip to reduce the cost of Nearby Search.

Please help me because I don't understand anything anymore.